# Speed of software RAID 0 with 4 SSD drives is strange

Tags: 16.04, ssd, raid, disk, mdadm

### Situation:

I have a server working on **Ubuntu Server 16.04**. I created software **RAID 0** array that contains 4 **SSD** disks.

When I checked the speed of the RAID array on my server I was confused. I was supposed to see that read speed is about **1200 MB/s** (300 MB/s * 4) and write speed is about **1100 MB/s** (300 MB/s * 4 - %). But, instead I saw only **860 MB/s** for read speed and **80 MB/s** for write speed.

I decided to check if this issue is connected to hardware. So, I created RAID 0 that contains 4 SSD disks, but now on my **desktop**. Every single hardware component is different there + it's **Ubuntu Desktop 16.04** (AMD-64).

When I checked the speed of the RAID array on my desktop I saw only **696 MB/s** for read speed and **178 MB/s** for write speed. So, now I'm sure that it's **Ubuntu 16.04** problem or **SSD disk** problem.

What are the causes of this issue and how to solve it?

Thanks for help

#### RAID configuration:

1. `sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=0 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sdc /dev/sdd /dev/sde /dev/sdf`
2. `sudo mkfs.ntfs -F /dev/md0`
3. `sudo mkdir -p /mnt/md0`
4. `sudo mount /dev/md0 /mnt/md0`
5. `sudo mdadm --detail --scan | sudo tee -a /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`

### Specifications:

#### Server:

`Operating system`: Ubuntu Server 16.04 (AMD-64) 
`SATA Interface`: II

#### Disks:

`Type:` SSD 
`Interface:` SATA III + SATA II 
`Capacity:` 480 GB 
`Controller:` Phison S11 
`Read Speed:` 560 MB/s 
`Write Speed:` 540 MB/s

• Full specifications you can get [there](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?reviews=all&Item=N82E16820225111) (tab *specifications*)

#### RAID:

`Level:` 0 
`Devices:` 4 
`File System:` NTFS 
`Read Speed:` 860 MB/s (not buffered) 
`Write Speed:` 80 MB/s

Comment: Why should the RAID 0 Write be any faster. You are writing 4 times the data over the same SATA Controller. RAID 0 is usually used for read intensive setups.
Is there any reason why you formatted the Disks NTFS? There are much faster alternatives.

Comment: Furthermore you should read about chunks there is no "answer" to what the correct chunk size for you is, it depends on the data you are going to store.

Comment: @Ben NTFS is used there because my SSD disks don't support linux file systems

Comment: @Ben RAID 0 is striping rather than mirroring, so the data is only written once, one quarter of the data to each disk.

Comment: @MaxMikhalchuk I think all SSDs should support whatever filesystems, including Linux. The specifications on Newegg you link to don't mention any limitations like that.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex when I try to create a partition with Ext4 filesystem it shows me some errors and after a few tries I get this partition, but when I use gnome file manager I'm not able to create a folder or a document (buttons are disabled). Also if you look at the [package](https://cdn.wccftech.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Wccftech-Patriot-Burst-480-GB-Box-1-1030x579.jpg) you'll see that it's not compatible with linux

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but it remains unanswered and probably the best kind of answer we're going to get is as follows:

There are many factors that can impact the performance you get from disks and without further information we're unlikely to know.  However given the information provided we could make some guesses.

These days most motherboards support full speed on each SATA controller, so I don't necessarily agree with comments above, but perhaps it was true for your controller.

Not least of which is manufacturers boasting about speeds which are either not correct, or not correct in a sustained way.  Even comparing something like a recent Seagate FireCuda with an equivalent Intel or even older - the Intel manages a better more consistent performance and the FireCuda takes almost twice as long for the same task.

I also did come across this thread on Reddit, [Buyer Beware: SATA SSD's with Phison S11 controllers](https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/comments/90glkw/buyer_beware_sata_ssds_with_phison_s11_controllers/), which suggests your SSD's controller specifically as having issues with I/O, however further down it does refer to a different model.  I suspect in this case you might have come across this - keeping firmware of the SSD up to date and the motherboard is one of the best ways to remove these kinds of barriers.

To a large extent the file system does not make a lot of difference, but it can if it's not set up well, but again I agree it's not likely this issue.

With SSD's trim can also be an issue that can slow things down.  Hopefully you've sorted it by now, but maybe these ideas help someone else coming along this path.